# No irrelevant A-marker, please?

Tags: google-maps

How do I link to a specific location without getting an A-marker at the nearest known address ?
Example: http://maps.google.com/?q=55.80707,12.428284&t=h&z=12
I only want to see the green arrow - not the (irrelevant) A-marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps doesn't allow this any more; the behaviour is only controllable in limited ways and Google are quite proud of their local search, with photos and things. What you *can* do is force the A marker to be your marker, and give it a label in the sidebar.

Enclose the label you want in round brackets. Use `+` to represent a space.

http://maps.google.com/?q=55.80707,12.428284+(My+point)&t=h&z=12